# iOS: only one table cell, but the screen is full of cell borders

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with 1 cell, but there are cell borders shown for rows that fill the whole screen. Why would UITableView draw cell borders for all those cells if there's only 1 cell? I would like my table to behave like the table view in the stock alarm clock app- it only draws as many cells as the table has. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting a table footer view

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Make sure to release that though, unless it's on ARC.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code;

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: This one certainly works too, but I checked the first answer by CSmith since it's shorter. Thanks though